# TCL Puts Output from Script to Variable

Tags: tcl

I have a TCL file called `procs.tcl` with a bunch of `proc`s. It gets sourced in my main script `main.tcl`.

procs.tcl

```
proc my_proc {args} {
  ...args parsing...
  ...use args to get $some_value...
  puts "set b $some_value"
}
```

main.tcl

```
...
set a 0
source procs.tcl
my_proc -send_var $a
...use $b...
...
```

I would like to evaluate `set b $some_value` which is returned from the `proc` within `main.tcl`'s scope so that I can use variable `b`'s value locally. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you using `puts` instead of `return`?

Comment: So would one way to state this problem be: "I want to "eval" the output of stdout generated when "procs.tcl" was sourced"?

Comment: @glennjackman, the script `procs.tcl` is written by a vendor, and it would be a huge pain to have that changed. I have already requested a change to use `return` instead but that may take a while, if they, in fact, do change it.

Comment: @andymango, yes that's precisely the root of the issue. I did play around a bit with open + pipe but wasn't successful.

Comment: Is there any chance that you're using the Tcl interpreter in a tool from Synopsys?  If so, they provide an extra Tcl command called `redirect` that lets you redirect any stdout to a variable.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHeithoff, it is from a non-standard vendor. I did try `redirect` but it doesn't work. The problem seems so simple to solve in Perl or some other similar languages, but I did not find much help on the internet with how to solve it in TCL.

Comment: I _knew_ we'd answered this before. The answers are moderately complicated, so repeating them is unlikely. (It's far better to just pass in the channel to write to as an argument or via a global variable.)